# how to solve the integral I get on the length of an arc?

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, definite-integrals, arc-length

I am to determine the arc length of a function given in parametric form of the form

$$x = 50 (1 - \cos(t)) + 50 (2 - t) \sin(t)$$
$$y = 50 \sin(t) + 50 (2 - t) \sin(t)$$

I must determine the arc length of a function given in parametric form of the form in the interval $t=0$ to $t=2$ **(it seems to me to be $2\pi$)**<--this does not
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=50 (2 - t) \cos(t)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=50 \cos(t) + 50 (2 - t) \cos(t) - 50 \sin(t)$$
$$\left (\frac{dx}{dt}\right )^{2}=2500((2-t)\cos(t))^2$$
$$\left (\frac{dy}{dt}\right )^{2}=2500 (\cos(t) + (2 - t) \cos(t) -  \sin(t))^2$$

$$50\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{((2-t)\cos(t))^2  + (\cos(t) + (2 - t) \cos(t) -  \sin(t))^2            }dt$$

$$\:$$

(**the result they propose is 100 units** <--this does not), after a long time I cannot find an acceptable identity to solve this integral.
Can you help me !!!
Edit :50 was missing before the integral

Comment: @Chinny84 He isn't missing the term. It cancels with one of the terms from the product rule on $$50 (2 - t) \sin(t)$$ so this is fine.

Comment: you are right! :)

Comment: Numerical integration on $(0,2)$ gives me something like $150.1$ as a solution. I'm not sure why you think integrating on $(0,2\pi)$ is the same as integrating on $(0,2)$. Perhaps you could elaborate on this and @ me once you have done so. If you are sure this is the correct parameterization then it looks like an answer of "100 units" comes from integrating over an interval of approximately $(0,.833)$.

Comment: @Chinny84 ,hello, how do you get there, I don't see it.

Comment: @vb628 ,hello, the problem has an error in the answer that is clear, thank you for your indication

Comment: @Lubin, hi ,you could have graphed the curve before making such a disparaging comment and by the way it is not a circle.

Comment: I must ask again, why do you switch from integrating on $(0,2)$ to integrating on $(0,2\pi)$? They are very far from being the same thing. Which interval are you supposed to integrate over?

Comment: @vb628 , edited above, everything that says "this does not" does not count, I don't know how to scratch the words.

Comment: My apologies, @BeTDa, and my thanks. I missed the multipliers of $t$ times the sine. And I seem to be a real expert at disparagement. Anyhow, I’ve deleted the comment.